# Count borrowed books by type

Tags: google-sheets, formula, spreadsheet

I am collecting stats for a small library.

I have people completing Google forms when they check out books. I have one field where they enter the call number for each book they borrow. These call numbers fall into three major classifications and take the following form (REF.XX.YYYY, FA.XX.YYYY, AA.XX.YYYY) where X and Y are a combination of letters and numerals. 
The result in the spreadsheet would look something like this:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHax2.png)

[Shared table](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oc2AJFoVmBw5tqN7629BXWF0nsaDdwT_sLQLleqQXKU/edit)

I am trying to come up with a way to count the number of instances each classification designation comes up (REF, FA, or AA) throughout the column. For instance, REF should be 3, FA should be 0 and AA should be 1. I made several tries with COUNTIF function but without any success. Any clue about what could be such formula?

The expected output is in red. I want to obtain such output using formulas.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try getting those classifications using regexextract and then use a query to count everything.

```
=ArrayFormula(query({A2:A\regexextract(B2:B; "^[A-Z]*")}; "Select Col2, count(Col1) where Col2 <>'' group by Col2 label count(Col1) ''"))
```

I've added this formula to your table. AA is not showing up in the result because it is not present in the source data.